# Python-like doctesting in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, documentation, doctest

One of my favorite features in Python (I know it's not really a feature of python) is doc-testing. For me it really augments standard documentation and helps to keep it up to data. Looking for something similar in Java, I've found JDocTest - http://cscott.net/Projects/JDoctest/ - last updated two years ago, and doctestj http://code.google.com/p/doctestj/ which haven't been updated since 2007.

Obviously, Java is not interpreter based like Python, but maybe there's some up to date library that enables doctest like capability in java?

Answer (score 7):

I know it's long time ago but I just found your post here while searching for something different.

In my company we built a java doctest library because we also like the idea of the python doctests. We're using it in one of our bigger projects to test and generate documentation with it.

You can find it here [at Github](https://github.com/bliss-doctest/doctest)